# Convert XML to HTML in following format PHP or Java

Tags: java, php, html, xml

here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><pdftsExtract><page number="0"><block height="10.425598" width="121.31714" xpos="75.384" ypos="695.5"><text>This is a test document.</text></block><text>&#13;
&#13;
</text><block height="63.34558" width="462.63947" xpos="72.024" ypos="616.3"><text><italic>Portable Document Format </italic>(PDF) is a file format used to represent documents in a manner&#13;
independent pdf application software, hardware, and operating systems.Each PDF file&#13;
encapsulates a complete description of a fixed-layout flat document, including the text,&#13;
fonts, graphics, and other information needed to display it. <bold>In 1991, Adobe Systems co-&#13;
founder John Warnock outlined a system called "Camelot" that evolved into PDF.</bold></text></block><text>&#13;
&#13;
</text><block height="89.31" width="466.7436" xpos="72.024" ypos="508.87"><text>While Adobe Systems made the PDF specification available free of charge in 1993, PDF remained a&#13;
proprietary format, controlled by Adobe, until it was officially released as an open standard on July&#13;
1,2008, and published by the International Organization for Standardization as ISO 32000-1:2008. In&#13;
2008, Adobe published a Public Patent <bold>License to ISO 32000-1 granting royalty-free rights for all&#13;
patents owned by Adobe that are necessary to make, use, sell and distribute PDF compliant&#13;
implementations.</bold></text></block><text>&#13;
</text><block height="41.76004" type="table" width="478.87598" xpos="66.62401" ypos="451.50998"><block height="13.920044" width="159.62599" xpos="66.62401" ypos="479.34998"><block height="8.279999" width="26.727844" xpos="72.024" ypos="482.71"><text>Name</text></block></block><text>     </text><block height="13.920044" width="159.62" xpos="226.25" ypos="479.34998"><block height="8.279999" width="35.868988" xpos="231.65" ypos="482.71"><text>Address</text></block></block><text>     </text><block height="13.920044" width="159.63" xpos="385.87" ypos="479.34998"><block height="8.279999" width="31.651733" xpos="391.27" ypos="482.71"><text>Mobile</text></block></block><text>&#13;
</text><block height="13.919983" width="159.62599" xpos="66.62401" ypos="465.43"><block height="8.279999" width="24.243843" xpos="72.024" ypos="468.79"><text>Richa</text></block></block><text>     </text><block height="13.919983" width="159.62" xpos="226.25" ypos="465.43"><block height="8.279999" width="44.347687" xpos="231.65" ypos="468.79"><text>Velachery</text></block></block><text>     </text><block height="13.919983" width="159.63" xpos="385.87" ypos="465.43"><block height="8.279999" width="50.198975" xpos="391.27" ypos="468.79"><text>123456789</text></block></block><text>&#13;
</text><block height="13.920013" width="159.62599" xpos="66.62401" ypos="451.50998"><block height="8.279999" width="38.88288" xpos="72.024" ypos="454.87"><text>Bhuvana</text></block></block><text>     </text><block height="13.920013" width="159.62" xpos="226.25" ypos="451.50998"><block height="8.279999" width="36.49826" xpos="231.65" ypos="454.87"><text>Chennai</text></block></block><text>     </text><block height="13.920013" width="159.63" xpos="385.87" ypos="451.50998"><block height="8.279999" width="50.198975" xpos="391.27" ypos="454.87"><text>987654321</text></block></block></block></page></pdftsExtract>
```

I want following html(with **bold, italic, table format**):

This is a test document.

*Portable Document Format* (PDF) is a file format used to represent documents in a manner independent pdf application software, hardware, and operating systems.Each PDF file encapsulates a complete description of a fixed-layout flat document, including the text, fonts, graphics, and other information needed to display it. **In 1991, Adobe Systems co-founder John Warnock outlined a system called "Camelot" that evolved into PDF.**

While Adobe Systems made the PDF specification available free of charge in 1993, PDF remained a proprietary format, controlled by Adobe, until it was officially released as an open standard on July 1,2008, and published by the International Organization for Standardization as ISO 32000-1:2008. In 2008, Adobe published a Public Patent **License to ISO 32000-1 granting royalty-free rights for all patents owned by Adobe that are necessary to make, use, sell and distribute PDF compliant implementations.**

Name AddressMobile
    RichaVelachery123456789
    BhuvanaChennai987654321

Comment: what is your question, sir? do you expext this site to act as your workbench ?

Comment: I have to convert above xml file into html file with all properties like font size, table format etc..Pls help..

Answer (score 2):

XSLT can be used and its pretty easy.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp